# Is there a way to understand how spark loads the classpath and in which order?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop2, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a spark job with custom spark on EMR and trying to use a custom jar in the driver extra classpath like

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar:/usr/local/java/avro-1.8.2.jar:/usr/local/java/avro-mapred-1.8.2-hadoop2.jar
```

But somehow it still loads the default avro jar (old 1.7.4) which i found via the class path verbose option

```
[Loaded org.apache.avro.generic.GenericContainer from file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar]
```

I want to understand as to in what order and priority the classpath gets loaded. Why its still picking the old generic hadoop avro 1.7.4 and not loading the one i want to use.

Is there a way to see the exact classpath order being loaded for a spark submit run, any jvm options etc would be helpful.

Simply saying the order of classpath (sequence, which goes first, my custome jar vs spark jars vs hadoop jars)

Comment: I generally shadow/shade the jar that I want to use and package it with the dependencies in the uber jar. Read more about it here : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297276/what-is-a-shaded-java-dependency

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, if two classes with the same full qualified name (package+classname) reside in the classpath (libraries or direct classes), the classloader may load the class from the one or the other jar in a way specific to the current classloader that loads the class.
You cannot not make any reasonable bet on its choices.

So having in the classpath two versions of a same library is clearly something to avoid : `avro-1.8.2.jar` and `avro-1.7.4.jar`.
The [spark.driver.extraClassPath](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) option will not change the way which the JVM works. It does just :

> Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of the driver.

Long story short : change the classpath value to specify only the version you need.